# Google calendar syncing - google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a problem in syncing my addon with google calendar. as in [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/calendar/conferencing/sync-calendar-changes#updating_the_google_calendar_event) says, to sync addon, we need to set a trigger to (create, update, delete) events in calendar and define a function to handle it:

```
var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('syncEvents')
.forUserCalendar(calendarId)
.onEventUpdated()
.create();
```

full code in [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/calendar/conferencing/sync-calendar-changes).

I'm trying to write and run my code [here](https://script.google.com/). and you can find logs in 'executions' in left sidebar.

!Note: I want to create an addon to have a 3rd party conference and it worked on create meeting.

my problem is when user update or delete an event, 'syncEvents' function should be call on update and delete but it's not working.

it should call in create too and it will cause I can see logs in executions tab but on update and delete there is nothing in logs.

any help make a nice wish in your life even if doesn't real help <3

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your script? From what I see in your answer, you have linked to the default Google Apps Script page. I have tested and the trigger is working for all the types of events (created, updated, or deleted).

Comment: thank you @Emel , I will comment a link to my script.but that will be awesome if you share your script too or link me somewhere to understand what should I do.

Comment: I am using [this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/calendar/conferencing/conferencing-sample), could you provide a sample of your script?

Comment: that is exactly what I used. could you get logs in syncing?

Comment: I made a mistake when adding the link. I simply have an [`onHomepage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons#Common.FIELDS.homepageTrigger) function that adds a trigger via `ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkCalendar') .forUserCalendar(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()).onEventUpdated().create()getUniqueId()`. With that minimal configuration, the `onEventUpdate` trigger is working

Comment: thank you @Emel this is good idea, but my problem is trigger will set to calendar but never called, I think somethings wrong with `onEventUpdate` cause everything seems fine but still nothing. I made a trigger in development (left side of app script page) and that worked but programmatically creating not working `-'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to google upgrade with new useless editor and ignore its bugs, change editor to classic and use old engine to fix the problem -_-

[here is a link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150756612#comment87) to where I found this solution. hope GOOGLE fix the issue.

[UPDATE]

just uncheck v8 runtime and problem will fix!

[image]